# Why `this===window` gives me false?

Tags: javascript

I've been testing the following code, but Firefox16 and Chrome22 gives me different outcomes.

```
console.log(this===window); //false in Firefox and true in Chrome
console.log(this.window===window); //true in both Firefox and Chrome
(function(){
    console.log(this===window); //false in Firefox and true in Chrome
    console.log(this.window===window); //true in both Firefox and Chrome
})();
```

As far as I can remember, Chrome's answer is right: Unless called with `new`, `this` is always same as the global object `window`, which leads to a pattern called scope safe constructors.

Comment: this.window is the safest choice, as it points to itself (ref. - [Eloquent JavaScript, chapter 9](http://eloquentjavascript.net/chapter9.html))

Comment: `console.log(this===window);` --- `true` in FF16.0.1

Comment: Interesting. In Firebug `this === window` is true, in the Firefox dev console it's false.

Comment: @ThiefMaster: they run in different scopes, nothing interesting ;-)

Comment: @zerkms: Then just displaying `this` should result in different objects being shown though...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is actually answered in the Firefox's [Web Console documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Web_Console) itself:

> Note: While using the Web Console, `this` is not the `window` object as it
>   would be in code running in content. This lets you create variables
>   without contaminating the content's namespace.

Comment: Oh, this info is quite helpful indeed.

Answer (score 5):

It is assumed that `window` is the global object, but until ES5, there was no specification to define that. It was just convention (i.e. part of "DOM 0"). In [ES5 §15.1](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.1), there is:

> in the HTML document object model the window property of the global object is the global object itself

Which I guess makes it a non–normative part of the ECMAScript standard at least.

For some time, there have been ambiguities between `window` and the global object, but for most uses, they were synonmuous. It was only certain cases where there were differences.

Regarding the statement:

> Unless called with new, this is always same as the global object window

Not at all. A function's `this` keyword is set by how the function is called. In non–strict mode, if, on entering an execution context, no `thisBinding` is provided, then it's set to the global object. In strict mode, it is left as is (i.e. it might be undefined, `null`, `0`, anything).

> which leads to a pattern called scope safe constructors

I'm not sure what that means. A function's `this` has nothing to do with scope. When the `new` operator is used with a function call, then the function acts as a constructor and its `this` is set to a new object created as if by `new Object()`. That seems to be more a function of the `new` operator than a concept of "scope safe constructors".

Comment: Interesting explanation on the difference between `this` and `window`.

Comment: @Rufus—it's one reason why you see `(function (window) {...}(this));` so that `window === globalObject`.